# Post-apocalyptic film, Steve McQueen, frozen world?

Tags: story-identification, movie, post-apocalyptic

Anyone remember a post-apocalyptic, frozen world film starring, I think, Steve McQueen? Something about lack of resources and "game of death" contest to keep the population down?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I checked Steve McQueen's full film list as an actor on IMDB and didn't seem to be any matches to your description.

May be this? [Quintet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quintet_%28film%29)

> Quintet is a post-apocalyptic science fiction film by Robert Altman produced in 1979. It features among others Paul Newman, Brigitte Fossey, Bibi Andersson, Fernando Rey, Vittorio Gassman and Nina Van Pallandt.

...

> The story takes place during a new ice age. The camera tracks a blank, frozen, seemingly deserted tundra until two blurry, distant figures can just be made out.

...

> Essex is unaware that the current Quintet tournament is a fight for the survival of the fittest. Those who are "killed" in game are executed in real life.

Comment: That's it! Must be getting old, or worse, "non-functioning". Can't believe I mixed up Newman and McQueen. Might be time to ride the conveyor belt up to the motherboard grinder. Get separated for my constituent (not so precious)metals. Blessings on you and all your ken.

Comment: @FlyMeToTheMoon: everyone mixes up actors. there are famous pairs, the pair that comes to mind is dustin hoffman and al pacino (i think i am not the only one for those two). Never confused newman with mcqueen but they are both sort of similar types, both leading men, around the same age. never heard of this movie which probably means it does not show on tv much.